# After enbaling VPN/NAT on 2008 R2 direct access to server is blocked (RDP, FTP,...)

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, firewall, nat, rras

After setting up VPN with NAT over RRAS configuration menu in windows server 2008 R2, direct access to server is blocked.
Does anybody know why is this happening?
How to enable RDP, FTP, and other direct (not over VPN) access to server?

Comment: Is access blocked always, or just when a VPN is established?  If the later, then it is most likely a routing issue.

Comment: @Zoredache thanks for comment, after establishing VPN connection everything is OK, but I don't want to force all users to establish VPN connection just download a simple file...